# Side help which follows and collapses to a tab (JQuery/Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add a help box at the right hand side of my page. I want it to stay in the same place as the user scrolls and I want it to collapse to a tab at the right hand side, when they close it.

A bit like this:

https://www.elated.com/articles/css3-floating-follow-tab-with-rollover-effects/

but it needs to expand and collapse.

I can't see any examples of how to do this anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you'll find much better implementations of this, however this is one way to do it. I just threw it together, I would google around to find something that may be a bit better but this should give you an idea of how it *could* be done.

Note this is with a jquery library you could use vanilla javascript as well. In order to have something happen `on click` you will need to use javascript. If you want it to happen `on hover` this can be done with just css.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', "#helpbar span", function(){
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('closed')){
      $(this).parent().removeClass('closed').addClass('open');
      $(this).find('p').text('CLOSE');
    }else if($(this).parent().hasClass('open')){
      $(this).parent().removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
      $(this).find('p').text('HELP');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#content{width:400px;}
.closed{
width:0px;
}
.open{
width:200px;
}
#helpbar{
  position: fixed;
  right:0;
  height:500px;
  border:1px solid black;
  top: 50px;
}
#helpbar span{
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left:-100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
}
#helpbar span p{
width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ornare vel dui eget viverra. Aliquam ac hendrerit ex, pulvinar dictum nisl. Quisque vitae ullamcorper augue. Donec congue rhoncus augue, eu faucibus erat bibendum a. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla facilisi. Quisque vehicula ex ut arcu convallis molestie. Nunc sed mi eget purus aliquet consectetur in eget ex. Cras commodo arcu augue. Duis at nulla ligula. Donec id erat non ante viverra sollicitudin sodales vitae velit. Mauris vitae fermentum nulla, eget laoreet erat. Donec in eleifend ligula. Phasellus in pretium enim. Vestibulum ultricies ligula arcu, sed faucibus risus vulputate vitae.

Integer ut erat magna. Sed imperdiet est vitae est rhoncus lacinia. Proin molestie tristique neque ut condimentum. Duis consectetur varius aliquam. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam at iaculis ipsum. Integer enim lacus, suscipit mollis consequat nec, lobortis sed magna. Cras ut ultricies arcu. Nulla aliquam magna nulla, ac venenatis nibh tincidunt in. Nulla tristique mauris orci, et sagittis dolor volutpat ut. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam lectus magna, bibendum eu mauris in, lobortis dictum ipsum. Donec molestie imperdiet feugiat. Pellentesque consequat laoreet ipsum, ac rutrum nunc tempus sit amet. Integer et cursus ex.

Morbi suscipit vitae leo ut consectetur. Maecenas vehicula libero ante, et pharetra ligula varius sed. Integer in lacinia augue. Cras tincidunt justo metus, vitae laoreet orci sollicitudin et. Quisque eu lobortis nisi, vel congue purus. Maecenas malesuada feugiat euismod. Etiam eu justo sed orci semper elementum. Cras et enim gravida, cursus sapien in, consectetur ante. Praesent maximus semper convallis. Praesent sit amet massa sagittis, interdum elit pulvinar, varius erat. Vestibulum ornare, ex id porttitor luctus, odio turpis imperdiet lectus, ac vulputate ipsum metus a dolor. Curabitur et leo nunc. Quisque in nulla ac lectus tempor tempus in quis ipsum.

Cras turpis lectus, volutpat vitae hendrerit vel, sollicitudin sed massa. Suspendisse non sagittis turpis. Quisque a lacus quam. Aenean laoreet lorem at ante viverra viverra. Duis volutpat eros a lacus posuere, non faucibus massa ultrices. Ut imperdiet mi in neque porttitor finibus ac eget arcu. Aliquam quis pharetra nibh, non sagittis neque. Curabitur arcu mauris, euismod ut libero ac, facilisis malesuada sapien. Maecenas ex lectus, suscipit eget nulla molestie, placerat varius leo. Pellentesque eu sapien fringilla, blandit nisi hendrerit, lobortis nunc. Cras ac felis ullamcorper, suscipit metus nec, semper diam. Vivamus quis mauris eget metus condimentum luctus eu non est.

In viverra turpis lacus, id porttitor nibh aliquam euismod. Sed a massa dolor. Aliquam ut commodo quam. Mauris a rutrum quam, non convallis enim. Suspendisse non turpis ultrices, congue nisl eu, fringilla mauris. Donec sed libero felis. Morbi vel lorem nibh. Pellentesque vitae accumsan nisi. Vivamus ut nulla sapien. Donec at diam laoreet mauris gravida mollis. Nullam tortor ante, auctor dignissim molestie ut, tempor nec urna. Vestibulum suscipit ultrices turpis vel tristique. Curabitur fringilla magna vel tortor finibus, ac commodo ipsum accumsan. In rhoncus eleifend enim, eu malesuada ex laoreet ut. Integer elementum sem sed aliquet gravida. Aenean auctor a justo vel ultrices.

Proin accumsan, ex eget hendrerit sodales, urna leo auctor nunc, sed imperdiet tellus sem nec sem. Proin vitae enim ut ipsum blandit dapibus. Fusce tellus tortor, ultricies vel lobortis et, iaculis ut massa. Quisque ullamcorper nulla urna, sit amet sodales risus facilisis a. Nulla in augue at urna pulvinar iaculis a ut nibh. Mauris ornare magna et gravida mattis. Maecenas euismod semper dictum. Maecenas nec risus justo. Proin id iaculis felis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Praesent fermentum vestibulum dui et pellentesque. Duis gravida risus rhoncus, dapibus orci a, finibus leo. Vestibulum maximus sagittis nibh non lacinia.

Nulla sodales odio at orci lobortis luctus. Nulla condimentum a libero at ullamcorper. Etiam in tincidunt ex. Donec non dolor nec augue tincidunt pretium vitae a odio. Aenean fringilla massa erat, in molestie mauris tincidunt eu. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed tincidunt turpis eu justo condimentum fermentum. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce mi mauris, ullamcorper at euismod a, mattis et purus.

Proin pharetra arcu ut maximus condimentum. Nullam sit amet vestibulum massa, at vulputate ipsum. Curabitur pretium ultrices sem. Pellentesque ullamcorper orci quis nisi finibus posuere. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec porttitor justo eget mi lobortis, iaculis gravida libero gravida. Donec in tempus nulla.

Curabitur suscipit ligula sit amet mi pharetra ultrices. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla facilisi. Duis quis lectus vitae arcu mattis fermentum at non lacus. Praesent ullamcorper nibh eu ante aliquam, sed fringilla tellus vehicula. Praesent ut mollis risus. Nullam nec dictum orci. Nullam egestas, erat eget vestibulum viverra, felis arcu facilisis massa, ac rutrum tortor est vel libero. Sed fermentum lacus sed massa pellentesque, a ornare orci interdum. Morbi in turpis risus. Donec ullamcorper, quam et blandit varius, quam lorem vulputate turpis, in viverra lectus tortor efficitur ipsum. Suspendisse dictum convallis est, quis bibendum dolor aliquam ut. Aenean hendrerit sapien fermentum dapibus gravida. Morbi eu pulvinar urna. Morbi scelerisque fermentum luctus. Sed ac tortor bibendum, pretium dui tempor, facilisis risus.

Mauris a lorem tristique, euismod lorem quis, varius risus. Donec bibendum nisi sit amet lorem auctor tempus. Nullam maximus erat quis lacus tristique, non aliquet neque semper. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis elementum, dui in euismod fermentum, mi nisi suscipit erat, vel tincidunt neque felis id felis. Suspendisse tempor mi quam, sed posuere nisl fringilla vel. Mauris vitae diam vehicula urna feugiat facilisis cursus sed ligula. Cras iaculis luctus nisi, quis dictum lacus venenatis ut. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus sit amet lacus diam.

Duis sem libero, pellentesque sed porta hendrerit, elementum commodo dui. Suspendisse felis metus, semper at urna sed, egestas ullamcorper dolor. Fusce eleifend, libero nec euismod posuere, sapien dui maximus est, ut congue lacus diam sed mi. In vitae est sed augue sodales pharetra. Donec sit amet sem magna. Integer ultricies in leo ut mollis. Vestibulum mattis varius erat, sed tempus augue finibus et. Donec feugiat accumsan diam eu efficitur. Nulla eu enim nec urna vehicula vehicula ac euismod dolor. Ut lacinia elit eget aliquam laoreet. Nullam dapibus imperdiet sem et pharetra. Nulla sed quam id turpis porta varius. Mauris dictum a tortor cursus scelerisque. Morbi eu mattis ante. Vestibulum efficitur accumsan diam et ultricies. Nullam pharetra nulla ut augue gravida, sed tincidunt dolor porttitor.

Sed molestie, massa sed mattis tincidunt, sapien velit bibendum lorem, in feugiat risus dui eu mauris. Quisque iaculis laoreet tellus, eget fringilla neque tincidunt et. Fusce metus tellus, euismod nec ornare nec, eleifend vel nunc. Donec et aliquet metus, sed tristique est. Mauris non aliquet urna, eget rutrum enim. Etiam posuere felis eget lacus pellentesque, ut dapibus dui vehicula. Proin vel fermentum ligula. Suspendisse accumsan a velit lacinia mollis. Fusce imperdiet id nisi quis maximus. Curabitur convallis eros nec hendrerit volutpat. Suspendisse vestibulum nibh urna, sed cursus odio euismod vitae. Morbi ornare tempor eros ut scelerisque.</p>
<div id="helpbar" class="closed">
<span><p>HELP</p></span>
<div>
<p>This is where the help is</p>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly the functionality I require. I have been Googling but couldn't find anything. I must be using the wrong search words.

Comment: you should google `jquery animate width toggle` `fixed position sidebar` `jquery on click` and `position element outside of parent div`